# XCode 4.2 Compiler Error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, llvm

When I create a new Project with XCode 4.2 (a Single View iOS App, for instance) the main.m-File in the "Supporting Files"-Folder looks like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "iiiAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int retVal = 0;
    @autoreleasepool {
    retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([iiiAppDelegate class]));
    }

    return retVal;
}
```

The Compiler Setting (in Build Settings) is the Apple 3.0 LLVM. When I change it to GCC 4.2 or GCC4.2 LLVM it shown errors with the main.m.

There is no `@autoreleasepool`...

Which Setting in my Xcode can cause such troubles? Why is the standard compiler for new projects the Apple 3.0LLVM instead of the system default compiler (GCC4.2)??

Answer (score 6):

To answer your first question:

> Which Setting in my Xcode can cause such troubles?

The compiler itself is the setting.  Change it to LLVM 3.0 and no more troubles

To answer your second question:

> Why is the standard compiler for new projects the Apple 3.0LLVM instead of the system default compiler (GCC4.2)??

LLVM 3.0 ***IS*** the system default compiler for Xcode 4.2.

I think what you are *actually* asking is how to fix the error when not using LLVM 3.0.  To do that, you would want to replace `@autoreleasepool` with `NSAutoreleasePool` like so:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int retVal = 0;

    // @autoreleasepool {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([iiiAppDelegate class]));

    [pool drain];
    // }

    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`@autoreleasepool` is a new feature added in LLVM 3.0. It just cannot work using the other compilers you tried.

Comment: And how can I reset the options, that the autogenerated code for new projects is compileable with the GCC 4.2?

Comment: Not sure if this is possible at all - maybe the templates are made just like this (but haven't checked). This now gets close to NDA, better ask on developer.apple.com