# How/where do I declare instance variables in the interface, implementation, program format for writing objective-c code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, instance-variables, nsautoreleasepool, declare

I am using Programming in Objective-C 4th edition by Stephen Kochan to teach myself Objective-C.  As a beginner, I do not yet understand how to debug, and even when I copy and paste code out of the book into Xcode I get errors. This is an example of a code I got from the book that will not compile:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
//---- @interface section ----
@interface Fraction: NSObject
-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n; 
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
@end
//---- @implementation section ----
@implementation Fraction {
    int numerator;
    int denominator; 
}
-(void) print {
    NSLog (@"%i/%i", numerator, denominator);
}
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n {
    numerator = n; 
}
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d {
    denominator = d; 
}
@end
//---- program section ----
int main (int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool { 
        Fraction *myFraction;
    // Create an instance of a Fraction
        myFraction = [Fraction alloc]; myFraction = [myFraction init];
    // Set fraction to 1/3
        [myFraction setNumerator: 1]; [myFraction setDenominator: 3];
    // Display the fraction using the print method
        NSLog (@"The value of myFraction is:");
        [myFraction print]; 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The errors I am getting are "inconsistent instance variable specification" on line 12. After that it just keeps telling me that "numerator" and "denominator" are undeclared.  The final error I get for this program is that there is an "expected expression before the '@'token" in "@autoreleasepool".  What do I need to change to make it compile?  Thanks!!

Comment: which xcode version u use

Comment: I have copied your code into an Xcode 4.6.2 project and it compiled and ran without any warnings.

Answer (score 1):

I just got the same errors using GNUStep. Change the @interface declaration and set something like

```
@interface Fraction: NSObject {
    int numerator;
    int denominator; 
}

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n; 
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;
@end
```

That made the trick and compiled succesfully the program for me.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you copied the entire code into one single file. The `//---- @interface section ----` goes into the `Fraction .h` file, the `//---- @implementation section ----` into the `Fraction .m` and the rest is the content of the `main.m` file. However you shouldn't modify the content of `main.m`.

Comment: It is not compulsory to put interface/implementation into separate .h/.m files. In fact the code given in the question compiles and runs (on Xcode 4.6.2) without any warnings or problems.

Answer (score 0):

`@autoreleasepool` is a new feature, your compiler seems to be too old. See [autoreleasepool was not declared in this scope error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10468901/autoreleasepool-was-not-declared-in-this-scope-error).